json normalization record_path key not found
This post was edited to grab the actual JSON file (large) instead of the sample snippet that I extracted,(which works in this post).
I was wondering why I get a key error when i use record_path on this data set.
under the results key there are 2 nested keys named 'active_ingredients' and 'packaging'
when i normalize i get
result = pd.json_normalize(data['results'], record_path=["packaging"],meta=['product_ndc'])

the expected columns
package_ndc description marketing_start_date    sample  marketing_end_date  product_ndcs 

but when i add active_ingredients to the record_path list i get a key error.  The same goes for meta as well.  When i add the other columns like 'brand_name' and 'generic_name' to the meta list, I get a key error.  to see the keys
this doesnt work
result = pd.json_normalize(data['results'], record_path=["packaging","active_ingredients"],meta=['product_ndc','brand_name','generic_name'])

Thanks for any help
Here is the actual code I use to grab the data which produces the key error.
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests, zipfile, io, os

cwd = os.getcwd()
zip_url = 'https://download.open.fda.gov/drug/ndc/drug-ndc-0001-of-0001.json.zip'
r = requests.get(zip_url)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
z.extractall(cwd)

with open('drug-ndc-0001-of-0001.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

packaging_data = pd.json_normalize(
    data['results'], 
    record_path=["packaging"], 
    meta=['product_ndc', 'brand_name', 'generic_name']
)

active_ingredients_data = pd.json_normalize(
    data['results'], 
    record_path=["active_ingredients"], 
    meta=['product_ndc', 'brand_name', 'generic_name']
)


i paired it with your answer and getting the same issues I had before I posted the question.

@greybeard, dont edit my question again.  This is not academia, therefore I don't need nor did I ask for your grammatical edits.  If you cant add anything enlightening to the question to help out with the code, please stay away.

Maybe you should learn the definition of "should" as stated in the expected behavior.  Should means requested but not required.    "Thanks and other statements of appreciation are unnecessary, and, like other chitchat, SHOULD not be included".     If I want to show my appreciation, I will.

(There is stackoverflow META for discussing the workings of [stackoverflow / StackExchange.)

Read the editing guidelines.  "Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged; try to make the post significantly better when you edit"  Not one thing you edited made my question significantly better.

Greybeard stop adding your childish comments.  You have not added anything of value to this discussion.

When you specify multiple record_path entries (like "packaging" and "active_ingredients"), pandas expects that the second record_path ("active_ingredients") exists within every element of the first record_path ("packaging"), but, in your data, active_ingredients is not a nested property of packaging
Do this to solve this
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "meta": {
        "disclaimer": "Do not rely on openFDA to make decisions regarding medical care. While we make every effort to ensure that data is accurate, you should assume all results are unvalidated. We may limit or otherwise restrict your access to the API in line with our Terms of Service.",
        "terms": "https://open.fda.gov/terms/",
        "license": "https://open.fda.gov/license/",
        "last_updated": "2024-11-15",
        "results": {
            "skip": 0,
            "limit": 2,
            "total": 118943
        }
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "product_ndc": "73647-062",
            "generic_name": "MENTHOL, CAMPHOR",
            "labeler_name": "Just Brands LLC",
            "brand_name": "JUST CBD - CBD AND THC ULTRA RELIEF",
            "active_ingredients": [
                {
                    "name": "CAMPHOR (SYNTHETIC)",
                    "strength": "2 g/100g"
                },
                {
                    "name": "MENTHOL",
                    "strength": "6 g/100g"
                }
            ],
            "finished": True,
            "packaging": [
                {
                    "package_ndc": "73647-062-04",
                    "description": "113 g in 1 BOTTLE, PUMP (73647-062-04)",
                    "marketing_start_date": "20230314",
                    "sample": False
                }
            ],
            "listing_expiration_date": "20251231",
            "openfda": {
                "manufacturer_name": ["Just Brands LLC"],
                "spl_set_id": ["f664eb79-8897-3a49-e053-2995a90a37b4"],
                "is_original_packager": [True],
                "unii": ["5TJD82A1ET", "L7T10EIP3A"]
            },
            "marketing_category": "OTC MONOGRAPH DRUG",
            "dosage_form": "GEL",
            "spl_id": "16c906dd-6989-9a79-e063-6394a90afa71",
            "product_type": "HUMAN OTC DRUG",
            "route": ["TOPICAL"],
            "marketing_start_date": "20230314",
            "product_id": "73647-062_16c906dd-6989-9a79-e063-6394a90afa71",
            "application_number": "M017",
            "brand_name_base": "JUST CBD - CBD AND THC ULTRA RELIEF"
        },
        {
            "product_ndc": "0591-4039",
            "marketing_end_date": "20250930",
            "generic_name": "CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE",
            "labeler_name": "Actavis Pharma, Inc.",
            "brand_name": "CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE",
            "active_ingredients": [
                {
                    "name": "CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE",
                    "strength": ".05 g/mL"
                }
            ],
            "finished": True,
            "packaging": [
                {
                    "package_ndc": "0591-4039-46",
                    "description": "1 BOTTLE in 1 CARTON (0591-4039-46)  / 59 mL in 1 BOTTLE",
                    "marketing_start_date": "20150828",
                    "marketing_end_date": "20250930",
                    "sample": False
                },
                {
                    "package_ndc": "0591-4039-74",
                    "description": "1 BOTTLE in 1 CARTON (0591-4039-74)  / 125 mL in 1 BOTTLE",
                    "marketing_start_date": "20150828",
                    "marketing_end_date": "20250930",
                    "sample": False
                }
            ],
            "openfda": {
                "manufacturer_name": ["Actavis Pharma, Inc."],
                "rxcui": ["861512"],
                "spl_set_id": ["907e425a-720a-4180-b97c-9e25008a3658"],
                "is_original_packager": [True],
                "unii": ["779619577M"]
            },
            "marketing_category": "NDA AUTHORIZED GENERIC",
            "dosage_form": "SPRAY",
            "spl_id": "33a56b8b-a9a6-4287-bbf4-d68ad0c59e07",
            "product_type": "HUMAN PRESCRIPTION DRUG",
            "route": ["TOPICAL"],
            "marketing_start_date": "20150828",
            "product_id": "0591-4039_33a56b8b-a9a6-4287-bbf4-d68ad0c59e07",
            "application_number": "NDA021835",
            "brand_name_base": "CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE",
            "pharm_class": [
                "Corticosteroid Hormone Receptor Agonists [MoA]",
                "Corticosteroid [EPC]"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

packaging_data = pd.json_normalize(
    data['results'], 
    record_path=["packaging"], 
    meta=['product_ndc', 'brand_name', 'generic_name']
)

active_ingredients_data = pd.json_normalize(
    data['results'], 
    record_path=["active_ingredients"], 
    meta=['product_ndc', 'brand_name', 'generic_name']
)

combined_data = pd.merge(
    packaging_data,
    active_ingredients_data,
    on=['product_ndc', 'brand_name', 'generic_name'],
    how='outer'
)

print(packaging_data)
print(active_ingredients_data)
print(combined_data)


which gives
   package_ndc                                        description  \
0  73647-062-04             113 g in 1 BOTTLE, PUMP (73647-062-04)   
1  0591-4039-46  1 BOTTLE in 1 CARTON (0591-4039-46)  / 59 mL i...   
2  0591-4039-74  1 BOTTLE in 1 CARTON (0591-4039-74)  / 125 mL ...   

  marketing_start_date  sample marketing_end_date product_ndc  \
0             20230314   False                NaN   73647-062   
1             20150828   False           20250930   0591-4039   
2             20150828   False           20250930   0591-4039   

                            brand_name           generic_name  
0  JUST CBD - CBD AND THC ULTRA RELIEF       MENTHOL, CAMPHOR  
1                CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE  CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE  
2                CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE  CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE  
                    name  strength product_ndc  \
0    CAMPHOR (SYNTHETIC)  2 g/100g   73647-062   
1                MENTHOL  6 g/100g   73647-062   
2  CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE  .05 g/mL   0591-4039   

                            brand_name           generic_name  
0  JUST CBD - CBD AND THC ULTRA RELIEF       MENTHOL, CAMPHOR  
1  JUST CBD - CBD AND THC ULTRA RELIEF       MENTHOL, CAMPHOR  
2                CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE  CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE  
    package_ndc                                        description  \
0  0591-4039-46  1 BOTTLE in 1 CARTON (0591-4039-46)  / 59 mL i...   
...
0  CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE  .05 g/mL  
1  CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE  .05 g/mL  
2    CAMPHOR (SYNTHETIC)  2 g/100g  
3                MENTHOL  6 g/100g  

EDIT
I changed the naming to mirror your changes in your edit: The first script uses the variable names packaging_df, active_ingredients_df, and combined_df for the DataFrames related to packaging, active_ingredients, and their merged result, respectively, whereas the second script uses packaging_data, active_ingredients_data, and combined_data for the same purposes. The difference lies solely in the naming conventions, with no impact on functionality or logic. The output is the same, so if you still experience issues, it must come from something else, probably in something you do before.
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "meta": {
        "disclaimer": "Do not rely on openFDA to make decisions regarding medical care. While we make every effort to ensure that data is accurate, you should assume all results are unvalidated. We may limit or otherwise restrict your access to the API in line with our Terms of Service.",
        "terms": "https://open.fda.gov/terms/",
        "license": "https://open.fda.gov/license/",
        "last_updated": "2024-11-15",
        "results": {
            "skip": 0,
            "limit": 2,
            "total": 118943
        }
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "product_ndc": "73647-062",
            "generic_name": "MENTHOL, CAMPHOR",
            "labeler_name": "Just Brands LLC",
            "brand_name": "JUST CBD - CBD AND THC ULTRA RELIEF",
            "active_ingredients": [
                {
                    "name": "CAMPHOR (SYNTHETIC)",
                    "strength": "2 g/100g"
                },
                {
                    "name": "MENTHOL",
                    "strength": "6 g/100g"
                }
            ],
            "finished": True,
            "packaging": [
                {
                    "package_ndc": "73647-062-04",
                    "description": "113 g in 1 BOTTLE, PUMP (73647-062-04)",
                    "marketing_start_date": "20230314",
                    "sample": False
                }
            ],
            "listing_expiration_date": "20251231",
            "openfda": {
                "manufacturer_name": ["Just Brands LLC"],
                "spl_set_id": ["f664eb79-8897-3a49-e053-2995a90a37b4"],
                "is_original_packager": [True],
                "unii": ["5TJD82A1ET", "L7T10EIP3A"]
            },
            "marketing_category": "OTC MONOGRAPH DRUG",
            "dosage_form": "GEL",
            "spl_id": "16c906dd-6989-9a79-e063-6394a90afa71",
            "product_type": "HUMAN OTC DRUG",
            "route": ["TOPICAL"],
            "marketing_start_date": "20230314",
            "product_id": "73647-062_16c906dd-6989-9a79-e063-6394a90afa71",
            "application_number": "M017",
            "brand_name_base": "JUST CBD - CBD AND THC ULTRA RELIEF"
        },
        {
            "product_ndc": "0591-4039",
            "marketing_end_date": "20250930",
            "generic_name": "CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE",
            "labeler_name": "Actavis Pharma, Inc.",
            "brand_name": "CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE",
            "active_ingredients": [
                {
                    "name": "CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE",
                    "strength": ".05 g/mL"
                }
            ],
            "finished": True,
            "packaging": [
                {
                    "package_ndc": "0591-4039-46",
                    "description": "1 BOTTLE in 1 CARTON (0591-4039-46)  / 59 mL in 1 BOTTLE",
                    "marketing_start_date": "20150828",
                    "marketing_end_date": "20250930",
                    "sample": False
                },
                {
                    "package_ndc": "0591-4039-74",
                    "description": "1 BOTTLE in 1 CARTON (0591-4039-74)  / 125 mL in 1 BOTTLE",
                    "marketing_start_date": "20150828",
                    "marketing_end_date": "20250930",
                    "sample": False
                }
            ],
            "openfda": {
                "manufacturer_name": ["Actavis Pharma, Inc."],
                "rxcui": ["861512"],
                "spl_set_id": ["907e425a-720a-4180-b97c-9e25008a3658"],
                "is_original_packager": [True],
                "unii": ["779619577M"]
            },
            "marketing_category": "NDA AUTHORIZED GENERIC",
            "dosage_form": "SPRAY",
            "spl_id": "33a56b8b-a9a6-4287-bbf4-d68ad0c59e07",
            "product_type": "HUMAN PRESCRIPTION DRUG",
            "route": ["TOPICAL"],
            "marketing_start_date": "20150828",
            "product_id": "0591-4039_33a56b8b-a9a6-4287-bbf4-d68ad0c59e07",
            "application_number": "NDA021835",
            "brand_name_base": "CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE",
            "pharm_class": [
                "Corticosteroid Hormone Receptor Agonists [MoA]",
                "Corticosteroid [EPC]"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

packaging_data = pd.json_normalize(
    data['results'], 
    record_path=["packaging"], 
    meta=['product_ndc', 'brand_name', 'generic_name']
)

active_ingredients_data = pd.json_normalize(
    data['results'], 
    record_path=["active_ingredients"], 
    meta=['product_ndc', 'brand_name', 'generic_name']
)

combined_data = pd.merge(
    packaging_data,
    active_ingredients_data,
    on=['product_ndc', 'brand_name', 'generic_name'],
    how='outer'
)

print(packaging_data)
print(active_ingredients_data)
print(combined_data)



awesome explanation.  I was looking at a dataset on kaggle that used 2 items in the record_path but now i see that one is nested in the other like you said.  When it failed in my example, I was thinking that I probably needed to use a merge function, but thought I would take a shot and ask.

Hey Serge.  I edit my post with the full code that I use at the end of the post.  I am still getting key errors.

@Brad Edited my answer. But the logic is the same and the only thing I changed was the naming. Maybe that is where my initial solution and your application of it changed.

I lost the original edit where i responded to you yesterday.  I didnt realize the actual snippet works, so I included the actual code that pulls the JSON file that doesn't work and gives me a key error.

Reading through the documentation for pandas.json_normalize the record_path takes a str variable.
Thus you would need to create two dataframes for each record path and then merge them together based on a common field.

Sharing a more complete code snippet can be benefitial

Thank you for commenting, but the pandas documentation does state that record_path takes a str or list of str, with a default of None.
